# Clean up database from web application after browser disconnects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to create temporary tables during a session. When the session ends (user ends the browser connection) I would like the drop the temporary tables. So I need be able to call a function that reads the table names saved in say `Session["temp_tables"]` and query the database to drop them.

Comment: It sounds like you should be storing this data in the Session to begin with, not in the database, since you want to delete it when the session expires. I think we need a bit more info on what the data is that you're storing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the session end event in your global.asax file.

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
    //remove temporary table
}
```

This will run after the users session times out, and not necessarily when they close their browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions can end for a variety of reasons that aren't necessarily associated to a user finishing use of your website (i.e. timeout, machine restart, etc). Generally speaking, I usually avoid using ASP.NET session state.

A couple of alternatives might be:

1. Have the user tell you when they're done with the data (saved "sessions"). This has the benefit of being simple to implement & allow the user to leave\return at a later time and continue where they left off.
2. Have a "last used" value in the tables & set up a scheduled task to cleanup stale data.